# Jquery error : r.getClientRects with "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I'm trying to get the top of an element by this function :

```js
function getTop(par)
{
 var pos = $(par).offset();
 return pos.top;
}
```

I use this code with "this" when I click on a button :

```
var pass = this;    
verifPosition(pass);
```

And the corresponding function is here :

```
function verifPosition(element)
{   
    if(getTop(element)
```

And I have an error with the if(getTop(element)) :

> `jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: r.getClientRects is not a function.`

Do you know why ?

Do you know another way to get the top of an element ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the context of the `this` you're referring to

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: The this is refering to my button, when I click on it, i call this function : `var pass = this; verifPosition(pass)`